# Why is my std::vector.push_back throwing a bad_alloc exception

Tags: c++

I have a simple loop that reads in a text file and writes it into a character array. Here is the function

```html
void podBase::parseMailingAddyImacroOutput(string a)
{
 fstream inP(a, fstream::in);
 char *buffer = new char[50000];
 int sz_data = 0;
 int nComma = 0;
 string temp = "";
 string *ptr_temp = &temp;
 char z = ' ';
 bool check[3] = { false,false,false };
 _MailingAddy.resize(vectorEntries);
 _CityStateZip.resize(vectorEntries);

 while (inP.get(buffer[sz_data]))
  sz_data++;

 //inP.close();

 

 //3 Commmas
 //First comma: Owner Name
 //Second Comma: Owner mailing street & Num
 //Third Comma: City, State, Zipcode

 for (int i = 0; i < sz_data; i++)
 {

  z = buffer[i];
  if (!isComma(z))
   temp += z;

  if (isComma(z))
   nComma++;

  if (nComma == 1 && !check[0])
  {
   temp.clear();
   check[0] = true;
  }

  if (nComma == 2 && !check[1])
  {
   _MailingAddy.push_back((temp));
   temp.clear();
   check[1] = true;
  }

  if (nComma == 3 && !check[2])
  {
   _CityStateZip.push_back(temp);
   temp.clear();
   check[0] = false;
   check[1] = false;
   check[2] = false;
   nComma = 0;

  }



 }

 


}
```

Upon execution, the program crashes at the line:

```
if (nComma == 2 && !check[1])
    {
        _MailingAddy.push_back((temp));
        temp.clear();
        check[1] = true;
    }
```

trying to execute "push_back"
With the reason of "bad_alloc". Regardless of what I try to push_back into the vector, I get this error - So I don't think its a problem of the std::string temp variable. I have done similar methods in this same program many times and have never come across an issue like this. Any insight would be welcome!

Comment: Just a few comments. 1) "\_MailingAddy" this is not a valid name. All identifiers starting with underscore followed by upper-case letter (and all identifiers containing double underscore "__") are reserved for the implementation. 2) "char *buffer = new char[50000];" - why raw pointers and manual memory management in modern C++? Use smart pointers and container classes from the standard lib. 3) Clean up your use of newlines and indentation - it's inconsistent. 4) consider using `auto` to avoid repeating types.

Answer (score 5):

You're leaking 50k memory every time you call `parseMailingAddyImacroOutput` so presumably you ran out of memory.

Comment: That function is called exactly once, so no memory leak.

Comment: @NnamdiNwajagu but you are still leaking 50k of memory... You are missing the `delete []`

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why the error wasn't thrown earlier in the program but the error stemmed from the buffer array being too small. Doubled the size and the error is gone.

Comment: This is likely to be a total hack, masking the actual bug. Don't just throw random amounts of memory at the problem. Use a bounds-checking container of the proper size for what you are doing.